# How can I show that X is locally compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

How can I show that if $X$ is such that there is a partition of the unit $(f_i)_{i\in{I}}$ over X where for each $i \in{ I}$, $\overline{\{x:f(x) \neq 0\}}$ is compact, then $X$ is locally compact.

I was trying to do it like this:

> We have that all open $X$ coverage supports a partition of the unity
> subordinate to it locally finite. And that by definition a partition
> of the unit  $(f_i)_i\in I$ is said to be subordinate to a coverage
> $\mathcal{C}$ if for every $i \in I$ exists $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such
> that $f^{−1}_s []0, 1]] ⊂ C$.
>
> The fact that it is locally finite gives us that for every $x ∈ X$, there is open V such that $x ∈ V$.
>
> I need to show that for every $x \in X$ there is open $V$ such that $x \in V$ and $\overline{V}$ is compact.

However, I got stuck in here. So, if someone could help me I would really appreciate.

Comment: Do you have that at each point $x \in X$, there are only $n(x) \in \Bbb{N}$ nonzero members of $\{f_i:i \in I\}$?  If so, I might look at where each of these $n$ functions is $> 1/n$ to pick a local open cover...

Comment: "The fact that it is locally finite gives us that for every $x \in X$, there is open V such that $x \in V$." No, this is just stating the $V$'s form a cover. Local finiteness is irrelevant.